# Apt-get is broken after install Google Cloud SDK on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: unix, ubuntu-18.04, apt-get, unixodbc, google-cloud-sdk

I was installing the Google Cloud SDK on my Ubuntu VM using the following commands

```
# Add the Cloud SDK distribution URI as a package source
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list

# Import the Google Cloud Platform public key
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -

# Update the package list and install the Cloud SDK
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk
```

and I think its broken now.

```
 apt-get install unixODBC unixODBC-dev
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/ cloud-sdk: /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/ cloud-sdk: /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Is there anyway to fix it so I can continue to download packages.

Comment: hey, Vinay Try updating apt by following command: 

sudo apt update

If this will not solve your problem, then try to release all change info by following command: 

sudo apt update  -y --allow-releaseinfo-change

Comment: Tried your suggestions. It did not work

Comment: In my case, it was a new system and I needed to install "curl" first

Answer (score 239, accepted):

I got into a very similar situation today by not following the [installation instructions](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/#deb) carefully enough. What I think happened is that I accidentally pasted and executed some of the commands that were only supposed to be run i*f you had trouble with any of the previous steps*.(The ones having "**Troubleshooting Tip**" above them.)

It looks like I "solved" it now by by removing these files

```
sudo rm /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg
sudo rm /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg~ 

sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
```

and then following the installation instruction again (more carefully this time) to install Google Cloud SDK.

Comment: It also works for `google-cloud-cli` installation.

Answer (score 22):

**Remove the existing sdk by running single command:**

```
sudo rm /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg && sudo rm /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg~ && sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
```

**Install google cloud sdk by running the single command**

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates gnupg && echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list && curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add - && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-java && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python && gcloud init
```

Hope this issue will be fixed.

Answer (score 4):

I followed all these commands (for trying to reproduce error in system)

1st command

```
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
```

2nd command

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -
```

3rd command

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk
```

4th command

```
sudo apt-get install unixODBC unixODBC-dev
```

above command prompted 
E: Unable to locate package unixODBC
E: Unable to locate package unixODBC-dev

Then I installed all the gCloud sdk dependencies By below command
5th command

```
sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-java google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python google-cloud-sdk-pubsub-emulator google-cloud-sdk-bigtable-emulator google-cloud-sdk-datastore-emulator kubectl
```

All above commands are given by you except 5th one,

I am unable to reproduce that error in my machine,

But it seems Your apt needs to clean up signed certificats and reconfigure again..

refer below link it might help you.

https://www.fossmint.com/keep-ubuntu-system-clean/

and please let me know about the solution if you got..

feel free to discuss on the same.

Comment: i got an error `E: Unable to locate package unixODBC` & `E: Unable to locate package unixODBC-dev`

Answer (score 2):

This one solved it for me:

```
curl -fsSL https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo gpg --yes --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg
echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, here is how I fixed it

**Step 1: Remove sudo rm google-cloud-sdk.list**

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
sudo rm google-cloud-sdk.list
```

**Step 2: Reinstall Google Cloud again**

```
sudo snap remove google-cloud-sdk # skip if you had installed gcp sdk before
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates gnupg -y
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
sudo curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk
gcloud init
```

Ref: https://askubuntu.com/a/1389272

Answer (score 0):

In case of no such files found, you can remove related link in sources.list or sources.list.save. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

My laptop is running Debian 12 (Bookworm) and I was getting a similar error message after adding the key to the shared keyring and the respective entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Here are the usual steps:

1. download the latest key from the location provided by Google in the documentation (https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg), using your favorite method (`curl`, `wget`, `Ctrl-C/Ctrl-V`, whatever)
2. checked if the key is authentic (`gpg --show-keys /path/to/key.gpg` and verify the fingerprints)
3. move the file to `/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg`
4. create a new apt source file under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` with the following entry:

   ```
   deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main
   ```
5. run `apt update`
6. install the desired packages

Pretty much the standard procedure for signed packages, however it was failing at the step 5, saying that the key had an invalid filetype.

It turns out the file provided by Google on that URL has `.gpg` extension, when in fact it should be `.asc`, as it contains the ASCII armored version of the GPG key, not the expected binary format.

Giving the GPG key file the correct extension `/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.asc` and changing the reference to the file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list` did the trick.